Stabilizers of higher dimensional maximally entangled state of non-$2^k$ dimension
Excluding normalization, the Bell state $\vert 00\rangle + \vert 11\rangle$ has stabilizers $XX$ and $ZZ$. I am interested in the stabilizers of the maximally entangled state on $d$-dimensions i.e.
$$\vert\Psi\rangle = \sum_{i=0}^{d-1} \vert ii\rangle$$
One thought was to express these in binary to obtain the representation below for $d = 4$
$$\vert 00\rangle + \vert 11\rangle + \vert 22\rangle +\vert 33\rangle = \vert 0000\rangle + \vert 0101\rangle + \vert 1010\rangle + \vert 1111\rangle$$
This is stabilized by $\langle X_1X_3, X_2X_4, Z_1Z_3, Z_2Z_4 \rangle$. For arbitrary $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $d = 2^k$, it seems that the stabilizer generators are $X_{i}X_{i+k}$ and $Z_iZ_{i+k}$ for $i\in [k]$ where $[k] := \{1,2 ... k\}$.
My questions are, is the above stabilizer set correct and what does one do for $d$ that cannot be expressed as a power of $2$?

Not sure whether this is heading in a direction, where you want to go, but a natural generalization of Bell states to higher dimensional representations is via higher spin representations of the Pauli algebra. Take a $d=2j+1$-dimensional Bell state as you defined it. We can write the Bell state as a symmetrization of a state of $4j$ qubits
$$\lvert \Psi \rangle = \delta^{(A_1}_{B_1} \delta^{A_2}_{B_2} \cdots \delta^{A_{2j})}_{B_{2j}} \lvert A_1 \dots A_{2j} \rangle \otimes \lvert B_1 \dots B_{2j} \rangle, $$
with the Kronecker Delta $\delta$ and the round brackets denote an index symmetrizer. Note that this is a different basis than you chose in your question, as I am writing a qudit state as a bosonic state $\lvert a \rangle = \delta^{(A_1}_{1} \cdots \delta^{A_a}_{1} \delta^{A_{a+1}}_{0} \cdots \delta^{A_{2j})}_{0} \lvert A_1 \dots A_{2j} \rangle$.
However, in this basis, naturally, $X^{\otimes 2j} \otimes X^{\otimes 2j} \lvert \Psi \rangle = \lvert \Psi \rangle$ as well as $Z^{\otimes 2j} \otimes Z^{\otimes 2j} \lvert \Psi \rangle = \lvert \Psi \rangle$. This has a nice graphical representation, see Penrose calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation). If you wish to express everything in a different basis, maybe this gives you a starting point.
EDIT: Example $d=3$
This corresponds to a Spin 1 representation. Consider the 2-qubit states $\lvert a \rangle = \lvert 00 \rangle, \lvert b \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\lvert 01 \rangle + \lvert 10 \rangle), \lvert c \rangle = \lvert 11 \rangle$ and define the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = {\rm span}\{ \lvert a \rangle, \lvert b \rangle, \lvert c \rangle \}$. Further define the following stabilizers as the effective action of Pauli $X \otimes X$ and $Z \otimes Z$ on $\mathcal{H}$, i.e.
$$ S_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \qquad S_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
$S_1 \otimes S_1$ and $S_2 \otimes S_2$ commute and leave the Bell state $\lvert \Psi \rangle = \lvert a a \rangle + \lvert b b \rangle + \lvert c c \rangle$ invariant.

By taking a symmetrization of $4j$ qubits, it looks like you already have that the total dimension restricted to a power of 2. Can you show how this works for the state $\vert 00\rangle + \vert 11\rangle + \vert 22\rangle$ where $d=3$ and the state cannot be expressed using qubits i.e. what are the stabilizers of that state?

I added the $d=3$ example.

There is an analogue of the Pauli group for $\mathbb{C}^d$ [1] generated by the matrices $$X = \sum_{k = 0}^{d-1} \vert{k+1}\rangle\langle{k}\vert, Z = \sum_{k = 0}^{d-1} \omega^k \vert{k}\rangle\langle{k}\vert,$$ and $\omega I_d$where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/d}$. Note that the addition in the bras and kets is done modulo $d$. These matrices are still unitary, but not Hermitian. If $d$ is prime, these matrices can be used to define non-binary stabilizer codes for $d^m$-ary qudits [2]. For the question, even if $d$ is not a prime power, one may verify that the one dimensional space spanned by  $\sum_{i = 0}^{d-1} \vert{ii}\rangle \in \mathbb{C}^{d} \otimes \mathbb{C}^{d}$ is the "stabilizer space" of the matrices $X \otimes X$ and $Z \otimes Z^{-1} = Z \otimes Z^{d-1}$.
